# Run Minidlna from RAMDisk

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, tmpfs, ramdisk

I am using Raspberry Pi to stream movies to my LAN.
The movies are mounted using sshfs and streamed with MiniDLNA.

Now the Pi has very slow SD-Card I/O, at iotop I can see minidlna uses <95% I/O speed.

- Now my Question is, if I could let minidlna run from ramdisk?
  As it is 'just' streaming it should be possible 'on-the-fly'?
  I tried to mount sshfs to Ramdisk, but no effects.

Comment: Don't use sshfs.

Comment: What should i use to mount the remote media directory?
The remote directory is in a datacenter not in my LAN

Comment: nfs (over vpn) is the best solution.

Comment: No Improvements, it is even slower than before, Disk I/O is higher even at very slow speeds.
Changed OpenVPN Server: TCP/UDP, MTU-TEST, Fragment,rcvbuf,sndbuf, fast-io.
I couln't get over 2 MB/s, Openvpn Client is i7 Laptop.... CPU Load etc. low, changing Cipher no effects.. This is very frustating